# Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i have ingress controller up and running in default namespace. my other namespaces have their own ingress yaml files. whenever i try to deploy that. i get the following error:

````
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "orchestration-ingress.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.default.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s: x509: certificate is valid for ingress-nginx-controller-admission, ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc, not ingress-nginx-controller-admission.default.svc```
````

Comment: What's the reason for deploying your **nginx ingress controller** in the `default` namespace ? As per [the docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)  the standard way of deploying it is placing it in `ingress-nginx` namespace. Just deploy it in `ingress-nginx` namespace and it should work fine. Your ingress resources can be deployed in other namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my error. i removed previous version of ingress and deployed this one.

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml